# Node.js synchronous prompt

Tags: node.js, prompt

I'm using the [prompt library](http://github.com/flatiron/prompt) for Node.js and I have this code:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    prompt = require('prompt'),
    toCreate = toCreate.toLowerCase(),
    stats = fs.lstatSync('./' + toCreate);

if(stats.isDirectory()){
    prompt.start();
    var property = {
        name: 'yesno',
        message: 'Directory esistente vuoi continuare lo stesso? (y/n)',
        validator: /y[es]*|n[o]?/,
        warning: 'Must respond yes or no',
        default: 'no'
    };
    prompt.get(property, function(err, result) {                
        if(result === 'no'){
            console.log('Annullato!');
            process.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
console.log("creating ", toCreate);
console.log('\nAll done, exiting'.green.inverse);
```

If the prompt is show it seems that it doesn't block code execution but the execution continues and the last two messages by the console are shown while I still have to answer the question.

Is there a way to make it blocking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since IO in Node doesn't block, you're not going to find an easy way to make something like this synchronous. Instead, you should move the code into the callback:

```
  ...

  prompt.get(property, function (err, result) {               
    if(result === 'no'){
        console.log('Annullato!');
        process.exit(0);
    }

    console.log("creating ", toCreate);
    console.log('\nAll done, exiting'.green.inverse);
  });
```

or else extract it and call the extracted function:

```
  ...

  prompt.get(property, function (err, result) {               
    if(result === 'no'){
        console.log('Annullato!');
        process.exit(0);
    } else {
        doCreate();
    }
  });

  ...

function doCreate() {
    console.log("creating ", toCreate);
    console.log('\nAll done, exiting'.green.inverse);
}
```

Comment: and if means a lot of problems?

Comment: Node.js is, by its nature, asynchronous. If this is not a good paradigm for your particular app it may be that Node isn't quite the right choice of technology for that particular use case. You really have to be willing to accept the asynchronous nature of the framework (tools like flow control libraries and patterns like function generators help a lot).

Comment: i've refactored the code a bit, really love nodejs non blocking i/o for most cases but now i'm trying to build a small command line utility and having a bit of problems with it since many if not all operations should follow an order in this part of the script and using the callback is not always possible.

do you know any good flow control libraries or patterns?

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, trying to create a Node tool similar to [Thor's actions](https://github.com/wycats/thor/blob/master/lib/thor/actions.rb). I really like the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library; `series` and `waterfall` might be especially useful for this particular task.

Comment: After messing around with it, I'm not sure async really helps any. Take a look at this Gist and see if it makes any sense: https://gist.github.com/77ce3468303351c06f29

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi, I myself was ending up in situations where my logic flow was synchronous when I started developing NodeJS applications. But as I started using libraries like **Socket.io** and **Request** I got used to the *Async* paradigm.

But anyways, I was using (and still am using) [Iced CoffeeScript](http://maxtaco.github.com/coffee-script/) when I need a synchronous flow.

But be warned that such libraries aren't as simple as they seem when using across multiple functions.

Answer (score 11):

With flatiron's prompt library, unfortunately, there is no way to have the code blocking. However, I might suggest my own [`sync-prompt`](https://github.com/shovon/sync-prompt) library. Like the name implies, it allows you to synchronously prompt users for input.

With it, you'd simply issue a function call, and get back the user's command line input:

```
var prompt = require('sync-prompt').prompt;

var name = prompt('What is your name? ');
// User enters "Mike".

console.log('Hello, ' + name + '!');
// -> Hello, Mike!

var hidden = true;
var password = prompt('Password: ', hidden);
// User enters a password, but nothing will be written to the screen.
```

So give it a try, if you'd like.

Bear in mind: **DO NOT use this on web applications**. It should only be used on command line applications.

**Update: DO NOT USE THIS LIBRARY AT ALL. IT IS A TOTAL JOKE, TO BE PERFECTLY FRANK.**

Comment: Cannot be installed on Ubuntu 14.04. `node-gyp rebuild`

Comment: better to use `prompt-sync` which doesn't require C++ bindings and works on all systems

Comment: "_Update: DO NOT USE THIS LIBRARY AT ALL. IT IS A TOTAL JOKE, TO BE PERFECTLY FRANK._" ❓ So `prompt-sync` it is? 

Comment: @ruffin no really. Do yourself a favour and use anything other than `sync-prompt`

Answer (score 8):

Since Node.js 8, you can do the following using async/await:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

function readLineAsync(message) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rl.question(message, (answer) => {
      resolve(answer);
    });
  });
} 

// Leverages Node.js' awesome async/await functionality
async function demoSynchronousPrompt() {
  var promptInput = await readLineAsync("Give me some input >");
  console.log("Won't be executed until promptInput is received", promptInput);
  rl.close();
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks

Comment: Since Node.js 18, this is even easier; require (or import) `require('node:readline/promises');` and you can `await rl.question(...)` directly (without need the readLineAsync wrapper function shown here).

Answer (score 3):

Old question, I know, but I just found the perfect tool for this. [readline-sync](https://github.com/anseki/readline-sync) gives you a synchronous way to collect user input in a node script.

It's dead simple to use and it doesn't require any dependencies (I couldn't use sync-prompt because of gyp issues).

From the github readme:

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

// Wait for user's response.
var userName = readlineSync.question('May I have your name? ');
console.log('Hi ' + userName + '!');
```

I'm not affiliated with the project in any way, but it just made my day, so I had to share.

Answer (score 3):

This is dependency free, synchronous and works on Windows, Linux and OSX:

```
// Synchronously prompt for input
function prompt(message)
{
    // Write message
    process.stdout.write(message);

    // Work out shell command to prompt for a string and echo it to stdout
    let cmd;
    let args;
    if (os.platform() == "win32")
    {
        cmd = 'cmd';
        args = [ '/V:ON', '/C', 'set /p response= && echo !response!' ];
    }
    else
    {
        cmd = 'bash';
        args = [ '-c', 'read response; echo "$response"' ];
    }

    // Pipe stdout back to self so we can read the echoed value
    let opts = { 
        stdio: [ 'inherit', 'pipe', 'inherit' ],
        shell: false,
    };

    // Run it
    return child_process.spawnSync(cmd, args, opts).stdout.toString().trim();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've come across this thread and all the solutions either:

- Don't actually provide a syncronous prompt solution
- Are outdated and don't work with new versions of node.

And for that reason I have created [`syncprompt`](https://github.com/cheddar-lang/syncprompt)
. Install it with `npm i --save syncprompt` and then just add:

```
var prompt = require('syncprompt');
```

For example, this will allow you to do:

```
var name = prompt("Please enter your name? ");
```

It also supports prompting for passwords:

```
var topSecretPassword = prompt("Please enter password: ", true);
```

Comment: I'm actually working in environment where I don't have python available, this failed as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Vorpal.js](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal) is a library I made that has just recently been released. It provides synchronous command execution with an interactive prompt, like you are asking. The below code will do what you are asking:

```
var vorpal = require('vorpal')();

vorpal.command('do sync')
  .action(function (args) {
    return 'i have done sync';
  });
```

With the above, the prompt will come back after a second is up (only after callback is called).

Comment: Doesn't look very synchronously.

Comment: Wow I must have brainfarted. I showed an async example instead of a sync one. I edited to include the sync version.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const buffer = Buffer.alloc(1024);
require("fs").readSync(process.stdin.fd, buffer);
console.log(buffer.toString());
```

Comment: This answer is a bit weird. For some reason, on Windows, `process.stdin.fd` does not register control sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prompt-sync](https://github.com/heapwolf/prompt-sync#readme)

```js
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')()

const ans = prompt('How many more times? ') // get input from the user.
```

P.S. prompt-sync acts weird, if prompt message contains new line character, so if you need multiline prompt just use `console.log()`:

```js
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')()

console.log('How many more times?\n')
const ans = prompt('') // get input from the user.
```